# Cross platforms hazard ratios

Tags: cox-model, hazard

**Context:** I have some hazard ratios defined on pCR expression data. Since I have to perform some external validation of my predictions I thought to use RNA seq data.

The reasons are two: (1) there's more availability of RNA seq data with respect to pCR on large cohorts of tumor samples, and (2) this will also prove that the model is robust independently from the platform used.

**Problem:** However, I don't know how and if it is possible to compare hazard ratios derived on two different data sources. I suppose a transformation is required in order to allow the comparison but I have no idea.

Can anyone help me please?